# google maps: find out coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates

i'm parsing some html data which has google maps embedded (displaying just one certain point) and i was wondering:

how can i find out the exact geographic coordinates of that point?

thx

Answer (score 3):

I will look into this further but if you are able to see the Google Maps representation, you can type this into your browser and it will pinpoint the exact center location:

```
javascript:void(prompt('',gApplication.getMap().getCenter()));
```

Very useful if you want to get quick lat/long values.  Is this the kind of info you need?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML files and want to find what point map is displaying?

This is likely not be possible (correct me if I am wrong). The map is a JavaScript object that only exists inside a browser - it is only text code in the html file. Map variables and data only exist inside the JavaScript engine running inside the browser, their dynamic variable state cannot be stored in a file ahead of time.

If the site is displaying a static map image then we have a different story. Just parse the URL to google static maps requesting the map image.

Answer (score 1):

i found out that the actual coordinates were stored in the html :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [LatLng Marker lab](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-maps-labs.html) in google map?